# Shehecheyanu at a Graduation

Tags: halacha, blessing, children-parenting, shehecheyanu, college-university-school

I recently attended a college graduation, and one of the parents decided to recite shehecheyanu to celebrate the occasion. I have never heard of someone doing this -- is there any basis for saying it?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with saying it?

Comment: The Bracha can be said on something that happens infrequently (check) and from which someone derives simcha from (check). Obviously its better not to blithely say brachos and thus some are makpid to buy a new suit or something and have that in mind to make the bracha

Comment: An even more appropriaet Bracha would be "Hatov Vehamaitiv"

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you'll look around the site and find other information that brings you joy, perhaps starting with our 24 other [tag:shehechayanu] questions. Please [edit your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/6600) and give yourself a name!

Comment: Nafkamina has a point. In my shul, the rav has a Bar Mitzvah boy's family (as well as himself) say Shehechiyanu in shul. In the case of college graduation, esp. if someone finally became a doctor after about 12 years between undergrad., grad. interns, etc. - I would also say "She'asah Nissim" ;-) ;-)

Comment: @Nafkamina Ironic, right?  I've bought more than 6 suits, but only had 3 graduation ceremonies.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman - suits are great for business too. If a new suit got you a salary raise, I would say shehechiyanu, hatov vehamitiv and even borei nefashos (there is an interpretation that "money" = "nefesh" as it is a form of "living" when used appropriately!)

Answer (score -3):

This prayer is a celebration of life. It can therefore be recited whenever something happens and which is a new experience. This includes graduation from school, college, etc. It seems to me that one could even say it on waking in the morning, although we do have other prayers for this.

Comment: Sourcing your initial sentance would be invaluable.

Comment: ... as well as the second.

Comment: as well as the last